# Pass a shared preference value using StringRequest so I can filter my SQL query

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm currently working on a listview inside a Fragment. It's working perfectly fine, but I need to filter the data on the listview using the user's username. How will I be able to pass the "username" using a request? Any help, advice, and tip will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Here's my code:

```
public class PendingFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String JSON_URL = "my_URL";
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_layout,null);

        //Fetching username from shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

        sendRequest();
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void sendRequest(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(PendingFragment.this.getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PendingFragment.this.getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String json){
        //showJSON function
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want send `username ` as urlparams or header to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can append user's `username` as a parameter to your `url` if its a `GET` request and for `POST` request you can use the other `constructor` of the `StringRequest` class,

[Volley GET POST example](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/android-volley-with-get-and-post-parameters-example/)

the above link contains samples to `GET` and `POST` request , you can get a overview of what i said,

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it!!

```
private void sendRequest(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(PendingFragment.this.getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", "YOUR_VALUE");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PendingFragment.this.getActivity());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```